# Angular EventEmitter not found

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a project by using Angular CLI, but when I try to use EventEmitter, it fails to compile with the error **"Can't resolve '@angular/core/src/event_emitter'"**

Here is the full error message

Failed to compile.

```
./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core/src/event_emitter' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\src\app'
@ ./src/app/app.component.ts 10:22-64
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
```

Here is the code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core/src/event_emitter';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private eventemitter = new EventEmitter<string>();
  title = 'My Application';
}
```

The file **"node_modules\@angular\core\src\event_emitter.d.ts"** exits.

I deleted node_modules folder, cleared npm cache (by using --force) and reinstalled all modules again with npm install, but still getting the same error.

I have no idea what can cause this, and I unfortunately couldn't find anything on internet related to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you are using vs code editor and this import statement was auto imported. Sometimes this went wrong.

Comment: @zgue, exactly. It was because of VSCode importing wrong library.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: Thank you! But.... why? The documentation says that the import should be <import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core/src/event_emitter';>

Comment: Toootally unaware you needed EventEmitter on the receiving side... thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

To try this :

```
@Output() deleteItem: EventEmitter<Item> = new EventEmitter();
```

I import use this :

```
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```